# back button on dialog is cancelling dialog even though I have a listener on it

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

I have a dialog show and I want that when the back button is pressed to ask the user to confirm he wants to cancel the dialog before the cancellation takes effect. Here is my code:

```
dialog.setOnCancelListener(new OnCancelListener(){

            @Override
            public void onCancel(DialogInterface arg0) {
                AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(dialog.getContext());
                builder.setMessage( "Are you sure you want to cancel?")
                       .setCancelable(false)
                       .setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                           public void onClick(DialogInterface diag, int id) {
                               diag.dismiss();
                               dialog.dismiss();

                           }
                       })
                       .setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                           public void onClick(DialogInterface diag, int id) {
                                diag.cancel();
                           }
                       });
                AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
                alert.show();               
            }

        });
        dialog.show();
```

The problem is that when back button is hit then my current dialog is cancelled then my "confirmation message" is displayed. How can I ensure the dialog is not cancelled until the user confirms that ?

Answer (score 6):

`onCancel` is called when a dialog is cancelled, that is why the confirmation message is displayed after the dialog is cancelled. You should `setOnKeyListener` for your dialog instead.

```
dialog.setOnKeyListener(new OnKeyListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onKey(DialogInterface dialog, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
            Toast.makeText(Activity.this, "back pressed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
});
```

Comment: Good but "return true" must be in the if-block, otherwise it consumes every key press.

Answer (score 0):

You could customize your base dialog like this way:

```
private void doCreateBaseDlg(){
    final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(this);
    dialog.setContentView(R.layout.activity_dialog_on_dialog_cutomize);
    dialog.setTitle("Title...");

    //this is the button in your customize layout
    Button dialogButton = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.dialogButtonOK);
    dialogButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            doCreate1stDlg();//here display your second conform dialog
        }
    });

    dialog.show();
}
```

I tried, and it works fine. hope could help you.